# Replacing Invalid CSV End of Line in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu, sed, terminal

What is the best way to locate all invalid \r\\n in a CSV document and replace with a valid \r\n using linux terminal?

From my research I have come across:

```
sed 's/\r$//'
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand the syntax and not sure if this would to the trick.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the difference between ‘*invalid \r\n*’ and ‘*valid \r\n*’?! Anyway, that regex will convert `\r\n` to `\n`, but only the first one. Add a `/g`. Or better yet: Just use `dos2unix`.

Comment: My apologies. The character was escaped from the view. I have updated :-)

Comment: Does the file contain carriage return-backslash-newline?!

Comment: So your file looks something like `line 1^M\nline 2^M\nline 3^M\n` ? Note those "\n" are actually just literal `\n` not a newline.

Comment: Yes @ Biffen. Also, I have removed quotes from question to avoid confusion. Thanks :-)

Comment: (@hawx If you want to reply to someone, don't put a space between the `@` and the username.)

Comment: @hawx There seems to be some confusion. Could you please clarify whether the file contains **A)** CR, backslash, the letter n (`\r\\n`, `0d 5c 6e`), or **B)** CR, backslash, LF (`\r\\\n`, `0d 5c 0a`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/\r\\$/\r/g'
```

Should do it. I.e. replace CR,`\` at the end of each line with just CR.

Note the `/g`. Without it `sed` would only replace the *first* match.

<sup><sup>`sed` doesn't (normally) ‘see’ LFs, since it's applying the regex line for line. `$` thus means the point where the LF is.</sup></sup>

Comment: if the file truly has `\r\\n` then it will be one long line as the `\ ` before n is escaped, meaning this won't work.

Comment: @123 I took OP's latest comment to the question to mean it's CR, backslash, LF.